# How sorting a Spreadsheet by Column Containing a Specific Title?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use this template to be able to sort the spreadsheet according to `Column I`:

```
function PlanteldoTimeA() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Dados Importados Time A');

    sh.getRange('B2:Z').sort({column: 9, ascending: false});
}
```

But sometimes the data for this column is not in `Column I`, I would like to define the column according to the title, which would be the value `number statistic game-minutes`

How could I do this?

I've already tried to retrieve these values with:
`var menu = sh.getRange('B1:Z1').getValues()`

and use:

```
if (menu == 'number statistic game-minutes') {
       sh.getRange('B2:Z').sort({column: menu, ascending: false});
}
```

But I was not successful.

Note 1: Titles are in `row 1`!

Image example:

[image]

Comment: Which row are your column titles in?

Comment: Sorry @Cooper , I added the question. They are on row 1!

Comment: Okay then example below should be what you want. Use `col['title']` to get the column number of that title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sortOnColumnName() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  const hr = 1;//header or title row
  const hA = sh.getRange(hr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let col = {};//provides column number for a given title
  hA.forEach((h,i) => {col[h] = i+1});
  //rest of your code
}
```